# Calling ERB without Rails: undefined method 'raw'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am using the [ERB engine](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) to generate an offline HTML version of a page of my Rails website. The page shows great when shown by Rails, but I have trouble generating with ERB by myself (despite using the same ERB template).

First I was getting the error `undefined method 't'` and I solved it by replacing all `<%=t(...)%>` calls with `<%=I18n.translate(...)%>`.

Now I get `undefined method 'raw'`. Should I replace all `<%=raw(...)%>` calls with something else? If yes, what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`raw` is defined as helper in actionpack/action_view library so that without rails you can't use it. But ERB templating shows its output without any escaping:

```
require 'erb'
@person_name = "<script>name</script>"
ERB.new("<%= @person_name %>").result # => "<script>name</script>"
```

And because of this for purpose of escaping there is `ERB::Util#html_escape` method

```
include ERB::Util
ERB.new("<%= h @person_name %>").result # => "&lt;script&gt;name&lt;/script&gt;"
```

Comment: I would prefer to use the same ERB file, not one with raw and one without... I added `include OutputSafetyHelper` (just like I already include my custom helpers), but get `uninitialized constant OutputSafetyHelper`

Comment: try `include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper`

Comment: Yeah, Marian is right. And don't forgot about `require 'action_view'`. And if you use Rails version prior 3.1.0 you should use `ActionView::Helpers::RawOutputHelper` instead of `OutputSafetyHelper `

Comment: I am on Rails 3.0.5. Inserting `require 'action_view'` followed by `include ActionView::Helpers::RawOutputHelper` at the beginning of my Ruby file solved the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just wanted to chime in and say to anyone who might end up here, because this always shows up on the front page of Google when searching for `RawOutputHelper`, that even if this question doesn't relate directly to your problem that Marian and WarHog are correct. That will solve any problems like ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::RawOutputHelper). I had some older code that included `RawOutputHelper` and kept getting that error. Since it wasn't showing up in the application trace I was really confused until I looked at the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

While @warhog 's answer will work, the `include` isn't necessary. It adds all the ERB::Util methods to the current class, which usually isn't desired and can cause unexpected side effects (if you had another `h` method for example). Instead just access the `h` method (or other helpers) using the ERB::Util class:

`ERB.new("<%= ERB::Util.h @person_name %>").result`