# Including external Ruby module inside a module?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module

I'm making a Rack framework for Ruby that runs a `App::Router` module inside of the following:

```
module App
    Router = HttpRouter.new do
        get('/') { |env| erb('home') }
    end
end
```

Notice the `erb()` method I wish to use in my router. The problem is getting the methods from an external source (my framework) into a module and get passed into the `do` block inside.

Is there there a possible way to get modules from an external source into a module in another file?

Thanks.

Comment: check this question and its answer out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950463/calling-erb-without-rails-undefined-method-raw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is erb a method you define somewhere? Try something like this:

```
    require 'path/to/module/with/erb_method'
    module App
      include YourModule
      Router = HttpRouter.new do
        get('/') { |env| erb('home') }
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
module App
  def foo
    "bar"
  end
end

module Route
  include App
end

include Route

foo
 => "bar"
```